# Linq Query Select from table1 where id in (select from table2 inner join table3 on table2 = table3 where table3 = id )

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, t-sql

I am looking to convert this T-SQL statement using ASP.NET-Core Context

```
    SELECT ID, SchemeCode, Name 
    FROM   Scheme SM                
    WHERE 
        SM.ParentID = 1             
    AND sm.[ID] 
                IN (SELECT dd.[Scheme_id]
                    FROM  dbo.[Employer_Detail] dd 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.[Employer] er ON dd.Employer_id = er.Employer_id
                    WHERE er.Employer_Parent_id = 123)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: no, not using this statement in sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
var npSchemes = from scheme in _context.Schemes
    join ded in _context.DeductionCodes on scheme.Id equals
    ded.SchemeId
    join er in _context.Employers on ded.EmployerId equals
    er.Id
    where scheme.ParentId == parentId && er.ParentId == employerId
    select new {scheme.Id, scheme.Code, scheme.Name};
    var result = npSchemes.GroupBy(sm => sm.Id).Select(grp =>
    grp.First()).ToList();
```